# Empathy for Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, instant-messaging, xmpp, empathy

Is there any way to build/install [Empathy](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Empathy) on Windows ?

I know there is Pidgin but I like Empathy more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Empathy](http://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/empathy/ci/master/tree/) can be installed on windows if you use [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/index.html)